# my laravel admin middleware redirecting to another url

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I am working on a project, i want to check if a user is an admin, if he is not an admin, he will be redirected to the login page, but if he is an admin, he will be redirected to the admin page, i initially made it the home url but later changed it to login url, so if the user is an admin it will redirect to the admin url but if his not, it will still he redirection to the home url instead of the login url that i changed it to here is the admin url code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Admin{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next){
        if(auth()->user()->isAdmin == 1){
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect('login')->with('error','You have not admin access');
    }
}
```

here is the web.php code

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');
Route::get('/about', 'PagesController@about');
Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');
Auth::routes();
Route::get('admin/routes', 'AdminController@index')->middleware('admin');
```

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: What is your outcome and your expected outcome?

Comment: If there is a logged-in user then the `LoginController` probably returns another redirect to the URL defined in the `$redirectTo` property. You could try changing that or use the browser developer tools to show all requests/responses.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, because you are redirecting user with route.

```
return redirect()->route('login')->with('error','You have not admin access');
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: It may be redirect to home page because if user already logged in then it will obviously redirected to home page

Answer (score 0):

Put route which called after access login in middleware.

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');
Route::get('/about', 'PagesController@about');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function() {
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');
    Route::get('admin/routes', 'AdminController@index')
});
```